# DynamoDB Scan With A Time Window Returning A Count Of 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB Column with timestamps that look like `2021-05-25 02:03:29.116`

I have a DynamoDB scan that I'm attempting to run that looks like

```
time aws dynamodb scan \
    --table-name "dev-main-rating" \
    --filter-expression "begins_with(pk, :search_filter) and "gis1_sk" BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date" \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":search_filter":{"S":"RATE#"},":start_date":{"S":"2023-01-01 00:00:00.000"},":end_date":{"S":"2023-06-14 00:00:00.000"}}' \
    --select 'COUNT'
```

which is returning an empty count

```
{
    "Count": 0,
    "ScannedCount": 5345702,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

I know there are at least some values in the time window specified because I've inserted one test record in the time window.

I'm trying to figure out how to either modify this query until it works or a different approach for time boxing my query results.

Comment: If you restrict the filter expression to `begins_with(pk, :search_filter)` temporarily, do you get results? Does at least one of these items have a `gis1_sk` between the start/end timestamps?

Comment: I do get results

```time aws dynamodb scan \
    --table-name "dev-main-rating" \
    --filter-expression "begins_with(pk, :search_filter)"  \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":search_filter":{"S":"RATE#"}}' \
    --select 'COUNT'
{
    "Count": 2308692,
    "ScannedCount": 5345702,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
aws dynamodb scan --table-name "dev-main-rating" --filter-expression       12.70s user 1.13s system 1% cpu 12:39.80 total
``` and at least some of them are in the time window.

Comment: Can you share one sample item that matches the time window.

Comment: Typically, in the absence of `--select 'COUNT'` at least, a scan will only process so many items (up to a max of 1MB of data or --max-items if supplied). It will return a LastEvaluatedKey if there are more items to scan. It's not unreasonable to expect it to find zero items matching the supplied filter in some of those partial scan operations. I'd run it without `--select` and see if you get zero matching items on the first scan, but you do get LastEvaluatedKey in the response.

Comment: @jarmod the Cli auto-paginates. I believe the issue is with the lexicographic matching of the strings used in the filter of the date.

Comment: @LeeHannigan you're right, thanks. I see that you have to indicate `--no-paginate` to get the default behavior of the underlying [Scan API request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html). It's one of those times where the behavior differs, but the docs for Scan and awscli scan are identical, right up until the last paragraph that describes  `--no-paginate`.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response. It turned out in my case that there were extra white spaces added to the timestamp which was causing a non-match.

Comment: @AlexLordThorsen, glad you figured it out. Please post your solution as an answer and mark it as Accepted or delete this question. This helps us keep the community more searchable and useful